# Bring terminated iOS app to Foreground state once internet is available

Tags: ios, objective-c

App works without internet and I'm storing user data in CSV file using `xcode`. When internet is available, I want to send this CSV file over the net weather the app is in terminated or suspended state. Is there a way around to bring app in foreground/background state from terminated/suspended state when internet is available?

Comment: Except for you developing in the `xcode IDE` what does this actually have to do with `xcode`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will be pretty annoying.

Whenever you loose a server connection to an app's instance, schedule a push notification. When that gets handled (e.g. the device is online and receiving the push), you may start a background task that uploads the data.

Besides abusing the push notification service and annoying your users (because of the decreasing battery life from the persistent networking and constant push notifications), you will need a massive back end to hold connections to all active app installations.

So, yes, but please don't.

**Edit**:

Since the data may only change when the app is 'alive', can't you rely on background fetch and background upload tasks, queueing unsuccessful uploads?

Comment: I think when app become alive I should send data in background thread. At the moment I'm unable to find any solution to bring the app from terminated/suspended state to foreground state when internet is available.